# Best practices for calling WebAPI endpoints from a Single Page Application

Tags: web-applications, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, single-page-application

I've built my webApi and I'm now putting together the front-end with knockout.  This might be a silly question but I'm a bit of a novice and want to make sure I'm thinking right.

Say you have a todoList with items in a list.  You let the user add an item to the list - the model updates it's "itemToAdd" array in the javascript viewModel.  When the user clicks "Save", the array of items gets updated client-side, immediately.  Is this the point at which a call to PUT /api/item would be appropriate?  If so, what is the "standard of behavior" if that PUT fails?  Take that item back out of the todolist viewModel and display an error?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how you want the user experience to be.

You can either not add the new items to the list on the client when they click the save button.  But show a spinner and let the user know your trying to save.  Any error messages the server returns you can display to the user. If the save is successfully then add them to the list.

Or you can add them to the list immediately after clicking the save button and let the user know that whats displayed has not been saved yet and they need to sync the changes back to the server.  Then send all the changes to the server when they choose too.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

You can do it either way, save first then show or the other way around (and undo if it fails).

But I think it is simpler to save first, because you do not have to think about undoing it if it fails.

Take a look at basecamp and see how they do it. If that works for you just do it the same way.